# How to prevent opening a new tab when I click the print button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-tables

I have created an application for printing an html table, the application is working fine, but the problem I am facing right now is that when I click the print option, a new tab with the data displayed in it is showing. How to prevent that tab opening and displaying?

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printTable");
   var divToPrint2 = $(divToPrint).clone().find('th:first, td:first-child').remove().end().prop('outerHTML');
   newWin= window.open("");
    var header = '<style>table th, table td {border-color: black;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;}table {border-collapse: collapse;}</style>';
    divToPrint2=header+divToPrint2;
   newWin.document.body.innerHTML = divToPrint2;
   newWin.document.head.innerHTML = header;
   newWin.print();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7okq2mm/)**

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the _self attribute shall make it open on same tab:

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

Comment: new tab is not opening but still the table content is displaying

Comment: Well, in that case you would need to first store the current HTML, do the printing and then revert back to initial HTML.

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't IMO support that. If you still need this, please post a comment here. If you got it working with this, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `printData()` function creating new window. And I think this function is not necessary. You can write print css for example:

```
@media print {
    // css code will be here. You can hide buttons and table column or something here.
}
```

And then you can just call `window.print()`. 
So I suggest this code:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
  window.print();
})
```

Comment: actually i want those functionality like removing the action column, plus applying the styling using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
newWin= window.open("","_self");
```

instead of

```
newWin= window.open("");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v7okq2mm/1/)

Comment: have you checked that demo, when you click the print still its showing the same stuff

Comment: new tab is not opening but still the table content is displaying